# How to align elements to the left and right using flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have this aqua container with 6 divs inside of it. I'm using flex-wrap to wrap the divs when they get too big for the current screen, however I want the first div on the top line to align to the left of the aqua container and the final div on that line to align to the right so even when a div gets pushed to a second line, the full space of the container is taken up and there is no empty space leftover.

I don't want to use space-between because I want the gap between each div to stay the same (32px).

What I have:
[image: Example]

code:

```css
.container {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 32px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you will have to change the width of the container to 964px. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLwdMbr

Comment: @paulie_D, but what if the screen gets smaller than 964px, I want it to be responsive?

Comment: Why don't you use media queries if you know the width of your divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, developing @Paulie_D's comment further:

It takes the 300px width of the single blocks and the 32px gap as given and not to be changed (that's what I understood from your question and comments), plus that there should be no "gap" right of the rightmost blocks.

The (centered) container has your 90vw `width`, but also a `max-width` of 964px (3 x the width of the blocks plus 2 x the gap)

In a media query the `max-width` is changed to 632px (2 blocks and 1 gap), starting at 1071px screen width. The 1071px are calculated as follows: 964 (the max. possible width with 3 blocks) divided by 90 (the 90vw) x 100 (full screen width). Same calculation principle for the 702px media query, where there's only one block per line.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 964px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 32px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

@media (max-width: 1071px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 632px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 702px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If you want your container (i.e. the aqua background)  to stay 90vw wide in all screen widths, you can erase all the `max-width`s and media queries, and simply use `justify-content: center` to center them, keeping the defined `gap` distance *between them*. This will of course result in varying left and right "paddings" of the container:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 32px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want the width of the container to be the same 90vw all the time?

Comment: @TiboMertens That's a contradiction: If the blocks width and the gap are fixed values, you either get empty space right of the rightmost blocks or you have to limit the possible container width.

Comment: Absolutely @Johannes is right either you fix the gap and the div's width then you have to control container's width either you fix the gap and container's width then let div expand to fill container

Comment: @TiboMertens I added a second version where the container is always 90vw and `justify-content: center` is used, which results in varying space/padding left and right of the blocks– see above.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, if I don't give my divs a fixed width, then I should be able to achieve what I described. Otherwise its impossible?

Comment: @TiboMertens Yes, the two solutions I provided are the closest to what is possible with fixed-width blocks and gaps

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use flex a shorthand property that combines flex-grow ,flex-shrink and flex-basis. As it is not possible to keep your div width and the gap constant and still fill the container, this what I suggest if your div width is not constant but the gap is to fullfill the whole container

```css
.container {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 32px;
}

.container div {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```